# How to write in Chinese: She is an English speaking secretary?

Tags: translation

How to write in Chinese: She is an English speaking secretary?

My version is: `她是英文的秘书。`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

English speaking - 说英语 / 会说英语:

她是`会说英语的`秘书

Answer (score 3):

While the accepted answer is correct, if "English speaking secretary" is a job title or similar, it's enough to use 英文秘书.

See e.g. this [job advertizement](http://www.104.com.tw/jobbank/custjob/index.php?r=job&j=603c44704638415833343c65546639619644c4426585e4023232323233c2d2827563j48).